# Inaccurate result searching by radius

Tags: distance, foursquare

When I search using radius parameter, It returns inaccurate results. For example, `radius=400`, it returns distance is greater than 400. I'm wondering if the distance is not the straight line distance? Or it is a bug from foursquare api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius parameter is "only valid for requests with intent=browse, or requests with intent=checkin and categoryId or query. Does not apply to match intent requests." [See documentation here.](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) Are you using a different 'intent'?